# Motion of Pressure Propelled Box

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics

The problem is this: Suppose there is a rigid box with known volume V in deep space that has an extremely pressurized gas inside of it (known pressure p), at some known initial temperature T, with initial velocity and position =0.

Now suppose that you poke a small hole in its side of known radius r.

The air will shoot out of the hole, effectively propelling the box in some way. Assuming that all of the air leaving the box has a velocity perpendicular to the hole, find the position of the box as a function of time.

Here are my attempts so far:

My first thought was to consider an infinitesimal mass leaving the hole at some velocity. If $\rho$ is the density of the air in the box, and $m_{air}$ is the mass of air in the box,  then this mass will have the form:

$$\begin{align}
dm_{\text{air}}  & = (\pi r^{2}) v_{\text{air}}(t)\rho dt \\
 & =(\pi r^{2})v_{\text{air}}(t)\left( \frac{m_{air}(t)}{V} \right)dt \\
\frac{ d m_{\text{air}} }{ d t }  & =\left( \frac{(\pi r^{2})}{V} \right)v_{\text{air}}(t)m_{\text{air}}(t) \\
& =\left( \frac{(\pi r^{2})}{V} \right)p_{\text{air}}(t) \\ \\
 & =-\left( \frac{(\pi r^{2})}{V} \right)p_{\text{box}}(t)
\end{align}$$

Seems like there are too many unknowns for me to use this, I'll need more. I then thought to consider it from a force perspective:

$$
\begin{aligned}
F_{\text{box}}  & =-F_{\text{air}} \\
 & =-\frac{P_{\text{air}}}{\pi r^{2}} \\
\frac{d}{dt}(p_{\text{box}}(t)  ) & =
\end{aligned}
$$

Again, it seems like this alone isn't very useful and I'm not sure how to combine it with the previous result (I thought Ideal Gas Law, but I didn't get anywhere with that) or where to go moving forward in a different direction.

It could also be the case that my initial attempts to solve this problem are way off. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a problem from a course or textbook, or did you just dream it up and wondered what the solution was.

Comment: Just dreamed it up!

Comment: Are you taking into account the mass of the tank?

Comment: Yes, as in I want to account for it changing.

Comment: In other words, the mass of the container M is included?

Comment: Yes, it's not explicitly written down but it is part of the $p_{box}$ term. The air currently inside the box is also a part of the $p_{box}$ term.

Answer (score 0):

Before you make the hole the force on left and right faces of the box are equal and opposite and there is no acceleration.

make a hole in right face.  now pressure force on right face will be a bit smaller than on left face.  Net force will now be to the left.

Force on box $=$ Pressure in box * area of hole $= m a$